# How to add a background image to a JFrame window in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am absolutely new in Java **Swing** development and I am finding some problem to add a background immage into a **JFrame** (into a windows of my application, that in this time have the classic gray background color of all Swing windows).

This is my class code:

```
package com.test.login;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class LoginFrame2 extends SingleFrameApplication {

    private static final int FIXED_WIDTH = 550;
    private static final Dimension INITAL_SIZE = new Dimension(FIXED_WIDTH, 230);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame2.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside startup()");


        JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();         // main JFrame that represents the Windows
        mainFrame.setTitle("XCloud Login");

        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(INITAL_SIZE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);

        Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();       // main Container into the main JFrame

        mainContainer.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Immagini/GUI 2.1/logo.png")));

        // JPanel creation and settings of the MigLayout on it:
        JPanel externalPanel = new JPanel();
        externalPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout("fill"));

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"), "w 50%, wrap");

        JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(20);

        externalPanel.add(userNameTextField, "w 90%, wrap");

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"), "w 50%, wrap");
        JTextField pswdTextField = new JTextField(20);
        externalPanel.add(pswdTextField, "w 90%, wrap");

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

        externalPanel.add(loginButton, "w 25%, wrap");

        mainContainer.add(externalPanel);
        //mainFrame.add(mainContainer);

        show(mainFrame);


    }

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to add it as background of the Container object by this line:

```
mainContainer.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Immagini/GUI 2.1/logo.png")));
```

But it doesn't work and the windows remains gray.

What am doing I wrong? Can you help me to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 3):

I see a couple of potential problems.

```
mainContainer.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Immagini/GUI 2.1/logo.png")));
```

Maybe the path is wrong and the image is never loaded.

But the problem is more likely is the following:

```
Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane(); 
mainContainer.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/andrea/Documenti/XCloud/Immagini/GUI 2.1/logo.png")));
...
mainContainer.add(externalPanel);
```

By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. You are attempting to add two components to the CENTER of the BorderLayout which is not allowed. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Border Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information.

If you really want a panel with a Background Image, then search the forum because this question is asked daily. All you need to do is look under the "Related" heading on the right to find some of these postings.